# How to use an if else statement in the middle of an echo

Tags: if-statement

I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';' in` which is for this line `if ($meta ==  '')` . Can someone provide a bit of guidance please, so that my if else statement works in this echo? Thank-you!!!

```
    echo '<tr>
            <th><label for="twitter_embed">Twitter Embed</label></th>
            <td><textarea name="twitter_embed" id="twitter_embed" cols="60" rows="4">'
             if ($meta ==  '') 
              { get_option('my_option_name');
               }else{ 
                .$meta. ;
                 }'</textarea>
            <span class="description">Use to embed tweets on your post.</span></td>
            </tr>';

    echo '</table>';
}
```

the `get_option` is for wordpress . Please can someone help with this if - else statement inside an `echo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the ternary operator instead: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
<?php
  echo '<tr>
        <th><label for="twitter_embed">Twitter Embed</label></th>
        <td><textarea name="twitter_embed" id="twitter_embed" cols="60" rows="4">'. 
        ($meta ==  '') ? get_option('my_option_name') : $meta 
        . '</textarea>
        <span class="description">Use to embed tweets on your post.</span></td>
        </tr>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the field where this is being shown in, the textarea is not being displayed. Only the text from the if statement is.